# release new version by google play api return 500 internal error

Tags: python, google-play, google-play-developer-api

At first, I upload new version bundle package by API was success. I can find the version on google play console , but can't find it by  calling api bundles().list and other api. when I try to release the version to a specified track, it will return 500 internal error on the commit step, no more other tips. what makes it be so?

```
 track_response = service.edits().tracks().update(
        editId=edit_id,
        packageName=package_name,
        track=TRACK,
        body={
            'track': TRACK,
            'releases': [{
                'name': 'My first API release',
                'versionCodes': [version_code],
                'countryTargeting': {
                    "countries": [],
                    "includeRestOfWorld": True
                },
                "releaseNotes": release_notes,
                #'userFraction': USER_FRACTION,
                'status': 'draft'
            }]
        }).execute()
commit_request = service.edits().commit(
        editId=edit_id, packageName=package_name).execute()
```

Comment: Please provide more information, like share the stack trace.

Comment: when upload an package must release a tack before commit.